# How can I use the Azure AD without single-sign-on

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

Basically I'm implementing an SSO for an employee portal that I'm making for us, but I'd also like to be able to access the graph API (At the least, the AzureAD REST API items, like adding/removing/getting users information) without having to be signed in through an SSO.

This way, I can use what I'm thinking to be some kind of API key/secret sort of setup and schedule cron jobs that interact with the AD in some way. Technically I could signin and set my account to be the one running this, but that seems kind of hacky and unreliable (as in, if something happens to my account, password expires, changes, etc... then the refresh token will no longer be valid and I'll have to sign in again and the task could be temporarily broken.)

I could have sworn I've seen documentation for this somewhere when I was looking into implementing this a few months ago, but I can't for the life of me find it now.

Really hope this isn't a duplicate, I just can't think of wording to search for that doesn't keep coming up with SSO-based API information.

**Update - Alright, it looks like I figured this out (with the help of Shaun Luttin's answer posted below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32618417/3721165 [link for convenience])**

So, all of the info Shaun brought together was really helpful. Initially the docs were fairly confusing due to how they word things, as well as the complexity of some of their examples. But once I got to digging through some of the examples, plus some of the info Shaun provided, and some experimenting/research on my own, I was able to come up with this (basic demo/concept):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;


namespace AzureADGraphApi
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string tenant = "...tenant id...";
        private static string clientid = "...client id...";
        private static string appkey = "...app key...";
        private static string aadinstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
        private static string graphResourceUrl = "https://graph.windows.net";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(graphResourceUrl + "/" + tenant);
            ActiveDirectoryClient adc = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await GetToken());

            IPagedCollection<IUser> Users = adc.Users.ExecuteAsync().Result;

            bool pagesLeft = false;
            do
            {
                foreach (IUser user in Users.CurrentPage)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
                }
                pagesLeft = Users.MorePagesAvailable;
                Users = Users.GetNextPageAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine("--- Page Break ---");
            } while (pagesLeft);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadinstance, tenant));
            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(graphResourceUrl, new ClientCredential(clientid, appkey));
            return result.AccessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

I found through further research that in order to use the Graph API the way I'm intending, you have to provide the graph resource URL (https://graph.windows.net) to the AquireToken method, instead of your app ID/URL.

So, I'm accepting Shaun's answer, but I also wanted to give my working result of that answer.

Thanks for the help, guys!

Comment: Are you wanting to do this programmatically or via a user interface only? If you are looking for a user interface only solution, then you are probably better off asking on ServerFault or a non-programming forum.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Programmatically. I essentially need to write a service that will execute (preferably one in PHP) at a certain time to maintain some custom information on the AzureAD users, and various other things. I saw your answer, as well, but I'm actually just heading home for the evening (5:03 here, yay!) so I'll check that out tomorrow morning. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you need is an access token without doing single-sign-on. The link that Rick Rainey provided will get you started.

You can obtain an access token programmatically by calling `AcquireTokenAsync`. There are lots of ways to call `AcquireTokenAsync` depending on the type of application you build and how you would like to authenticate. You will need to decide whether to create a Native Client Application or a Web Application.

[image: Web Application or Native Client Application]

Based on the application type, the way to authenticate differs a fair amount. It sounds like you would like to authenticate without a user prompt (i.e. not request to enter the username/password.) The following have worked for me, and do not involve a user prompt at all. Each of them use the following constants that you will need to grab from the manage.windowsazure.com portal. Let me know in the comments if you need help finding any of them.

```
private const string

    DIRECTORY_TENANT_NAME = "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com",
    DIRECTORY_TENANT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    RESOURCE_URL = "https://graph.windows.net",
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + DIRECTORY_TENANT_NAME,

    // web application
    CLIENT_ID_WEB = "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    CLIENT_SECRET_WEB = "xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx=",

    // native client application
    CLIENT_ID_NATIVE = "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

    // adminstrator
    USER_NAME = "myuser@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com",
    USER_PASSWORD = "xxxxxxxxxx";
```

Now the following three options open up to you (though there may well be others) for obtaining a token. I have tested each of the following and they all work so long as you have properly configured your Azure Active Directory tenant, users, and applications.

**AcquireToken(string resource, ClientAssertionCertificate clientCertificate)** works with Web Apps. The disadvantage of this approach is that it is harder to setup initially (PowerShell, certificate creation). The advantage is that once setup it is easy to use. With Native Client Apps it does not work and throws this error: `AADSTS50012: Client is public so a 'client_assertion' should not be presented.`

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY);
var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var certs = store
    .Certificates
    .Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "mvp2015", false);
var clientCertificate = new ClientAssertionCertificate(CLIENT_ID_WEB, certs[0]);
var result = authContext
    .AcquireTokenAsync(RESOURCE, clientCertificate)
    .Result;
```

**AcquireToken(string resource, ClientCredential clientCredential)** works with Web Apps. It is easier to setup and is easy to use once setup. Native Client Apps do not support this approach, because they lack a Client Secret.

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY);
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(CLIENT_ID_WEB, CLIENT_SECRET_WEB);
var result = authContext
    .AcquireTokenAsync(RESOURCE, clientCredential)
    .Result;
```

**AcquireToken(string resource, string clientId, UserCredential userCredential)** works with Native Client Apps. Web Apps fail with this error: `AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.` One gotcha is that the user with whom you are logging in must be configured correctly in your Active Directory.

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY);
var userCredential = new UserCredential(USER_NAME, USER_PASSWORD);
var result = authContext
    .AcquireTokenAsync(RESOURCE, CLIENT_ID_NATIVE, userCredential)
    .Result;
```

Once you have a token using your preferred method, you can then use the Active Directory Graph like this. For the sake of readability it is in a `Func` though you can put the `accessTokenGetter` into its own method.

```
Func<Task<string>> accessTokenGetter = async () =>
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false);
    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(CLIENT_ID_WEB, CLIENT_SECRET_WEB);
    var result = await authContext
        .AcquireTokenAsync(RESOURCE_URL, clientCredential);
    var token = result.AccessToken;
    return token;
};

var uriRoot = new Uri(RESOURCE_URL);
var uriTenant = new Uri(uriRoot, DIRECTORY_TENANT_ID);
var client = new ActiveDirectoryClient(uriTenant, accessTokenGetter);
foreach (var u in client.Users.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage)
{
    var n = u.DisplayName;
}
```

## Remarks

- The `DIRECTORY_TENANT_ID` is in the address bar of the web browser when we are in our Azure Active Directory tenant's dashboard. manage.windowsazure.com > Active Directory > Some Tenant.
- Once we have created our application within Azure Active Directory, we need to configure its permissions. This is at the bottom of our applications CONFIGURE tab. manage.windowsazure.com > Active Directory > Some Tenant > APPLICATIONS > Some Application > CONFIGURE.
- The demos above use two NuGet packages:

  - `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient` Version 2.1.0
  - `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` Version 2.19.208020213

## See Also

There is an example here: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/ConsoleApp-GraphAPI-DotNet

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed writeup! I'll be looking through all this for sure. Do you happen to know if there's a way to do this on the PHP side of things? I know C# .net, so it's not an issue writing it in C# (eventually the whole thing will be asp.net, when vnext comes out). Regardless, it's not a huge issue, I'm thinking I'll need to run it here anyway. The portal will be in the cloud, but the background service will be here since all of our systems are here, and I'll push info up to the portal for caching via a secure API.

Comment: Reading over it, to be clear: "AcquireToken(string resource, ClientCredential clientCredential)" Do I need to provide credentials on runtime each run, or can I do this the first time (say the initial setup of the app on the deployed server) and it (or windows) caches the access tokens? Then, secondly, if it does cache them is there any documentation on how long? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. The app caches the access tokens by default and keeps them in-memory. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.tokencache.defaultshared.aspx

Comment: Yes. It is possible thru PHP.

Comment: Alright, so, thanks for all the info first of all! I managed to get a working demo together using this method. I've included that in an update to my original post, but I've also accepted your answer (and referenced it.) Hopefully this is all able to help someone else as well! As for the PHP bit, it doesn't look like I'll be needing to do it in that. But, at the same time I don't really need/want to make something running in the background on PHP anyway. It turns out this is going to be quite a bit bigger, in the long run, so I'll go ahead and make it a C#.NET app anyway. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm trying 
AcquireToken(string resource, ClientCredential clientCredential)

Against the Power BI REST API. I get a token but requests return 403 Forbidden. Azure is new to me - I need info on how to diagnose auth issues. Any pointers?

Comment: really nice sum up? thumb up !

Comment: Why does AcquireToken(string resource, ClientAssertionCertificate clientCertificate) only work with web apps?  I have a console app that I want to contact Azure KeyVault to obtain secrets and I want it to authenticate using a Client Certificate.  Is client certificate based authentication not supported by non-web apps?

Comment: Is there a way to use "user credential" with webapps?

Comment: Ditto @Paul's question. Native apps work as app registrations for Dynamics CRM delegation, web apps don't. I require certificate authentication for my use case because my client has no way of keeping a secret, secret.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD *Service Principals* is what I believe you are after.  Here is documentation on how to create one for your app.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/